# How use IoC for empty constructor

Tags: c#, inversion-of-control, structuremap

I use 3-party library and I want to invoke custom constructor extend of empty constructor.

I use structuremap.

Is it possible ?

Source code from 3-party library:

```
  public static T InstantiateType<T>(Type type)
            {
                if (type == null)
                {
                    throw new ArgumentNullException("type", "Cannot instantiate null");
                }
                ConstructorInfo ci = type.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes);
                if (ci == null)
                {
                    throw new ArgumentException("Cannot instantiate type which has no empty constructor", type.Name);
                }
                return (T) ci.Invoke(new object[0]);
            }
```

I tried

```
 x.For<IJobFactory>().Use<StructureMapJobFactory>();
                x.ForConcreteType<StructureMapJobFactory>().Configure.SelectConstructor(() => new StructureMapJobFactory(container.GetInstance<IContext>()));
```

Comment: Does your code work? If no, what happens?

Comment: Also, do you want to instantiate the `T`, or the `type`?

Comment: hm.. I don't know, I think type. I setup correct type, but I need create by NOT empty constructor

Answer (score 1):

you can use this :

```
public static T InstantiateType<T>() where T : new()
{
    return new T();
}
```

Comment: I can't change the code. It is 3-party library source code